# how to set skb->priority of ARP packets

Tags: linux, networking, routing, vlan, arp

As the title already specifies, I'm looking for a way to set the linux `skb->priority` of outgoing ARP packets of a given interface on my linux machine that is used as a router.

The skb priority is ultimately used to set the IEEE 802.1Q priority through the egress priority map.

For regular IP/TCP/UDP traffic setting the priority is normally easy enough as it can be set through iptables (`-j CLASSIFY --set-class`), cgroups (net_prio), or others, but for the ARP traffic I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think etables with vlan module could be used to specify 802.1Q Tag Control Information fields

**Update**

vlan module is for matching packets not for setting priority

This [article](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-set-egress-priority-vlan-on-linux) explains how to set 802.1Q Tag Control Information fields

Comment: do you have a command line snippet to do that? because so far I haven't found a way to set or change the priority, the `--vlan-prio` argument is only for matching packets.

Comment: Indeed you are right the argument  ``--vlan-prio``  is only for matching packets. But I think this [article](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-set-egress-priority-vlan-on-linux) could help

Comment: nope, unfortunately not. it's doing exactly what I mentioned in the initial question: classifying IP traffic through cgroups and then mapping the classified traffic through egress mapping on to VLAN priorities.
This does not work for ARP traffic that the Linux kernel is producing on its own.

Comment: Let's forget about the skb data structure. I want to know what is exactly  your concern. Do you want to give arp packets some priority??

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. The ARP packets need to be sent on a 802.1Q VLAN with a PCP (priority) of 6. that is because of the nature of the network: some hosts will only respond to the ARP requests when sent with this particular priority. (I didn't choose that, it's just done that weirdly). And after searching around for some time I concluded that setting the PCP value could be easiest set by having the skb priority (which is used in many other places throughout the linux networking subsystem) set to some value and then used the egress priority mapping.

Comment: Take a look to [this document](http://open-lldp.org/dcb_overview)

Comment: It seems that you have to first use ``arptables`` and the ``CLASSIFY`` target as explained [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/arptables/arptables.8.en.html) to set the skb->priority and then set the IEEE 802.1Q priority through the egress priority map